# How to Replace Pydantic's constr for use outside of BaseModel in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm working with FastAPI and Pydantic for a project where I've used `constr` for string validation. This has been particularly useful for ensuring that string inputs adhere to specific constraints, like length and format, directly in the route function signatures.

[image]

Here's an example of how I've been using it:

```py
from pydantic import constr
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException

SiteCode = constr(strict=True, to_upper=True, max_length=4)

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/{site_code}", summary="Read a site")
async def get_site(site_code: SiteCode) -> str:
    return "..."
```

However, I've learned that constr is [deprecated](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/types/#pydantic.types.constr), and I'm looking for a modern replacement that aligns with current best practices in Pydantic and FastAPI. My goal is to maintain the same level of validation (e.g., strict, to_upper, max_length) for parameters passed directly to route functions, not just within Pydantic models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's said in the documentation that you should use `Annotated` with `StringConstraints` instead of `constr`:

```
SiteCode = Annotated[str, StringConstraints(strict=True, to_upper=True, max_length=4)]

@app.get("/{site_code}", summary="Read a site")
async def get_site(site_code: SiteCode) -> str:
    return site_code
```

https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.6/api/types/#pydantic.types.constr

Comment: Actually, it seems it was so apparent that I completely overlooked it. I assumed, though I'm not sure why, that such usage was restricted to within a model, and not freely outside like this. Thank you very much for your response.